# use VBA in excel to get data from closed workbooks with multiple file names

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that has a list of excel file names in one column and I need to use those file names to have a macro get data from one cell from each one of those files in the list. Where do I begin? Sorry for such a dumb question.
[workbook with data sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQZNT.jpg)
I would like to get data from a workbook whose name comes from column K, with the worksheet name coming from column L, and always cell A13. And put that value in the correct row in column M.

Comment: You'll need to open each workbook, try `Workbooks.Open` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Maybe I should be more clear. I want to know where I begin learning VBA, the syntax usage, structure, and the like with regards to this project. Should I use a macro or a script or am I confused about the difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have to do :

1. Iterate through each of the names (lets say  the list range is A1:A5)
2. Open that workbook.
3. Get the value from the cell
4. Paste that value on main workbook
5. Close workbook and go to the next one

This is how you do this:

```
Sub CopyFromWorkbooks()
Dim path As String
    path = "THE PATH WERE THOSE WORKBOOKS ARE SAVED (Eg: "C:\Users\YOU\Documents")"
            For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YOUR_SHEET_NAME").Range("A1:A5")
            'Open the workbook
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=path & "\" & cell.Value  'adding workbook name and path to get full workbook path

            'Copy cell value to this workbook
            Workbooks(cell.Value).Sheets("YOUR_SHEET_NAME").Range("THE RANGE TO COPY").Copy

            'Paste copied value in this workbook
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YOUR_SHEET_NAME").Range("THE RANGE TO PASTE").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            'Close Workbook
             Workbooks(cell.Value).Close True

             Next cell
End Sub
```

**This code as is will paste the copied data always on the same cell if you need help with that just write back ;)**

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm still lost. I can't get that to work even with a single cell. But i'm not sure if that code is exactly what I'm looking to do. Let me see if I can put up some screen shots.

Comment: Thanks the screenshots will certainly help, in the meantime i **corrected the code above, the "\" in the full path was in the wrong direction (/) see if it works now and if not also tell me the error you're getting**

Comment: Ahh got it to work now. Ok so I'm going to try and see if I can figure out how to do the entire list. Also I think it would be better if it didn't actually open the workbook. Correct?